# How to segregate users and groups from list of AD accounts?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I have list of accounts as below in a text file-

```
AccountName
Mahin\user1
Mahin\user2
Mahin\group5
user12
usert1
groupt3
```

This way, I have around 400 accounts (mix of various users and some groups), 
as you can see from above, some accounts have format as `<Domain>\<AccountName>`
and some with just `<AccountName>`.

I was trying to find a way to segregate users and groups from this list, 
how can I achieve this using powershell?

Looking for something like

```
AccountName, IsUser, IsGroup, IsExists
Mahin\user1,1,0,1
Mahin\user2,1,0,1
Mahin\group5,0,1,1
user12,1,0,1
usert1,,,0     //-> This Account DOES NOT EXIST, so, IsUser, IsGroup and IsExists (0) can be empty or some distiguishable number
groupt3,,,0    //-> This Account DOES NOT EXIST, so, IsUser, IsGroup and IsExists (0) can be empty or some distiguishable number
```

So far, I know how to get members of various groups using below script, but not sure of above part.

```
$groups = Get-Content "C:\AD\groups.txt"
$resultsarray =@()
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $resultsarray += Get-ADGroupMember -Id $group | select     
    samaccountname,name,@{Expression={$group};Label="Group Name"}
}
$resultsarray| Export-csv -path "C:\AD\output\GroupMembers.csv" -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Please show us the full expected output for your example (e. g. Mahin\user1, Mahin\group5)

Comment: Hi Jisaak, Kindly check the updated one

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Im not very familiar with the `Active Directory Cmdlets`, there is probably a better solution for this.

However, I would retrieve all users and groups first, then iterate over your text file and try to find any user or group:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -filter *
$groups = Get-ADGroup -filter *

Get-Content 'YOUR_FILE_PATH'| ForEach-Object {
    $adObject = $_ -replace '(.*)\\(.*)', '$2@$1' # fix search string

    if ($users | Where { $_.SamAccountName -eq $adObject -or 
        $_.UserPrincipalName -like "$adObject*"} )
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            AccountName = $_
            IsUser = $true
            IsGroup = $false
            Exist = $true
        }
    }
    elseif ($groups | Where Name -eq $adObject)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            AccountName = $_
            IsUser = $false
            IsGroup = $true
            Exist = $true
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            AccountName = $_
            IsUser = $false
            IsGroup = $false
            Exist = $false
        }
    }   
} | Export-csv -path "C:\output\GroupMembers.csv" -notypeinformation
```

On my `AD` I have to transform `Mahin\group5` to `group5@Mahin` and search for `group5@Mahin*`, thats why I replace the string within the script.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jisaak! How can we export the result to csv file?..  can I add this line to script for that? "$adObject | Export-csv -path "C:\output\GroupMembers.csv" -notypeinformation"

Comment: Just add `| Export-csv -path "C:\output\GroupMembers.csv" -notypeinformation` right after the last curly bracket

Comment: It throws syntax error if I add that line after last curly bracket

Comment: I edited my answer and added the csv export. Just copy it and change only the filepath, it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jisaak for you help, I ran the script with 4 accounts as source, script is still running for long.. I will update you once it finishes

Comment: Hmmm, `$users` and `$groups` can get really big if you have an big AD! I'm wondering what is better: Just two calls to AD and possible huge memory consumption or a call to AD for every line in your list.

Comment: I think if you run the script with 4 or 400 accounts, the script wont take more then 1 second longer. The first two lines (where I retrieve user and groups) take so long.

Comment: @OcasoProtal You are right, this depends on his needs. But I would try to do it this way because 400+ AD invokes will take their time...

Comment: @jisaak Yes of course! This was just a remark if some other users have the same problem but a bigger AD. The most elegant solution would probably be to use one call of `Get-Adobject` with the input list. But I don't know if thats possible.

Comment: Then you probably adopt th script and invoke the Get-AdUser with a filter for the current object (same with groups).